# I need help translating a math question from german to english.

Tags: linear-algebra, translation-request

I have a linear algebra question I need to translate from German to English. Here is the question. All your help is much appreciated:
[image: Problem 2 in German]

Here is the google translated piece:
Problem 2 (20 points)
We consider Rn with the standard scalar product. Let U⊆ Rn is an r-dimensional (0 ≤ r ≤ n) linear subspace with orthonormal basis B = {u1,. . . , ur}. Let PU : Rn → Rn, where the orthogonal projection onto U, defined by
            PU(v) =j=1r(uj,v) uj

(A) Show that PU is self-adjoint.
(B) Denote by U the orthogonal complement to U (see Series 9, Task 2).
Verify for all v ∈ Rn the Pythagorean theorem, ie the equality ∥ v ∥2 = ∥ PU(v)∥2 + ∥ P(v) ∥2
Note: Defining Graphic Design B by means of an orthonormal basis of U ⊥ to an orthonormal basis of Rn.
(C) It is to be Q = (u1 ... ur) ∈ M n, R (R) is the matrix of the base vectors u1, ..., ur ∈ B of U as columns. Show that the matrices A and B of PU of PU ⊥ with respect to the standard basis of Rn are given by.
A = QQt or B= E-QQt
(D) Now let U =  0  ⊂ R3. Calculate the matrix of PU ⊥ with respect to -1
the standard basis of R3 in two different ways: Use one hand the formula for B in (c). Use the other hand, the formula for A from (c), replacing U by U ⊥ and an orthonormal basis for U ⊥ elections.

Comment: Google translate, no?

Comment: tried it but it's not giving me complete translation which makes it harder to understand the question to solve.

Comment: I don't want to spend 10 minutes typing. What specifically can you not figure out?

Comment: @BobJones would be really nice and helpful (mostly for you) to type it in google translate and provide people who know the language "google-translated" version of the text so they can easily fix nonsense part, instead of retyping it from scratch. Let alone the image you posted is so small that one can hardly read it.

Comment: Google translation is not bad. What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\Bbb R^n$ equipped with the standard dot product and let $U \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be a $r$-dimensional ($0\le r \le n$) linear subspace with orthonormal basis $\mathcal B = \{u_1, \ldots, u_r\}$. Let $P_U: \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ be the associated projection on $U$, given by
$$P_U(v) = \sum_{i=j}^r <u_j,v>u_j$$

a) Show that $P_U$ is self adjoint.

b) Let $U^\perp$ be the orthogonal complement of $U$ (see p.9 ex.2) and verify the Pythagorean Theorem for all $v \in \Bbb R^n$, i.e.
$$||v||^2 = ||P_U(v)||^2 + ||P_{U^\perp}(v)||^2$$

Hint: Extend $\mathcal B$ via an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp$ to an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$.

c) Let $Q \in M_{n,r}(\Bbb R)$ be the matrix whose $i$-th column is given by $u_i \in \mathcal B$ for $i = 1,2, \ldots, r$. Show that the matrices $A$ of $P_U$ and $B$ of $P_{U^\perp}$ with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$ are given by
$$A = QQ^t \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ B = E-QQ^t$$

d) Now, let $U =  \left< \left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{matrix} \right) \right> \subseteq \Bbb R^3$. Caculate the matrix of $P_{U^\perp}$ with respect to the standard basis of $\Bbb R^3$ in two different ways: First, use the formula in c) to calculate $B$ and then use the formula in c) to calculate $A$, where we replace $U$ with $U^\perp$ and consider an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp$.

Comment: Thanks alot. Appreciate your help.